# return value of stored procedure based on different rules

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a stored procedure to get the values based on the following tables.

[image]

I am filling an apartment flats according to the nationality of the buyers.

The stored procedure has to return next non-occupied flat based on the following rules:

- If a new entry comes, I need to suggest the non-occupied flat  which is next to the occupied-flat having the same nationality of new person
- If no match found for above condition, then allocate first flat in a floor where no flats were occupied
- If no match found for above condition, then allocate a flat which is having at-least two empty flats on both sides
- If no match found for above condition, then allocate the first flat which is empty according to the sort order

NOTE:

- Each flat is identified by combination of Floor & Flat No
- Sort order for flat and floors while searching should be from 1 To n

**SAMPLE INPUT:** NAME: RANDY NATIONALITY: BRAZIL

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**: FLOOR:1 FLAT NO: 4 (w.r.t. to the attached image)

Comment: Can you post some sample input and expected output?

Comment: 1. A stored proc is unnecessary - this can be done with a query. 2. Seems inherently prejudiced to me

Comment: @DaleM can u help me out with those queries?

Comment: Yes but I have a ,oral problem with the question as phrased. Edit it so it is about putting coloured balls in boxes and I will have a go tomorroe

Comment: where is randy in your table  ??

Comment: @jWeavers that will be inserted into OWNER MASTER before calling this procedure. I ve given just a sample.

Comment: better you should give sample input and output as per your table data... otherwise people get confused...

Comment: These sorts of problems are often solved in a couple of ways, depending on the  expense of each query.  If the queries are trivial you can `UNION` together all of the results along with a ranking column and take the `TOP 1` ordered by rank.  If they are expensive then it is more efficient to select one query into a temporary table and if `@@RowCount` is zero proceed to the next query.  At the end you return the result from the temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to create columns for each of your criteria, i.e. one column for if the next door flat owner has the same nationality, a column for if the floor is empty.

You can then take all your criteria and place them within the order by of a `ROW_NUMBER()` function to get the flats in the order you defined. The key part in the below query is this:

```
RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PrevIsNationalityMatch DESC, 
                                        NextIsNationalityMatch DESC, 
                                        EmptyFloor DESC, 
                                        EmptyFlatsEitherSide DESC,
                                        Floor, 
                                        FlatNo)
```

The four columns (`PrevIsNationalityMatch`, `NextIsNationalityMatch`, `EmptyFloor', 'EmptyFlatsEitherSide`), are all bit fields, so if a row exists where the previous flat is owned by someone of the same nationality this will always be ranked one by the ROW_NUMBER function, otherwise it looks for if the next flat is owned by someone of the same nationality (I added this rule as it seemed logical but it could easily be removed by removing it from the order by), and so on and so on until it is left just sorting by floor and flat no.

```
DECLARE @NewOwnerNationality VARCHAR(20) = 'BRAZIL';
WITH FlatOwnerNationality AS
(   SELECT  FlatMaster.Floor, 
            FlatMaster.FlatNo, 
            FlatMaster.IsOccupied,
            IsNationalityMatch = CASE WHEN OwnerMaster.OwnerNationality = @NewOwnerNationality THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM    FlatMaster
            LEFT JOIN OwnerMaster
                ON OwnerMaster.OwnerName = FlatMaster.OwnerName
), Flats AS
(   SELECT  FlatMaster.Floor,
            FlatMaster.FlatNo,
            FlatMaster.IsOccupied,
            EmptyFlatsEitherSide = CASE WHEN PrevFlat.IsOccupied = 'NO' AND NextFlat.IsOccupied  = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            EmptyFloor = CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN FlatMaster.IsOccupied = 'YES' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY FlatMaster.Floor) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            PrevIsNationalityMatch = ISNULL(PrevFlat.IsNationalityMatch, 0),
            NextIsNationalityMatch = ISNULL(NextFlat.IsNationalityMatch, 0)
    FROM    FlatMaster
            LEFT JOIN FlatOwnerNationality PrevFlat
                ON PrevFlat.Floor = FlatMaster.Floor
                AND PrevFlat.FlatNo = FlatMaster.FlatNo - 1
            LEFT JOIN FlatOwnerNationality NextFlat
                ON NextFlat.Floor = FlatMaster.Floor
                AND NextFlat.FlatNo = FlatMaster.FlatNo + 1
), RankedFlats AS
(   SELECT  *,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PrevIsNationalityMatch DESC, 
                                                    NextIsNationalityMatch DESC, 
                                                    EmptyFloor DESC, 
                                                    EmptyFlatsEitherSide DESC,
                                                    Floor, 
                                                    FlatNo)
    FROM    Flats
    WHERE   IsOccupied = 'NO'
)
SELECT  Floor,
        FlatNo,
        MatchedOn = CASE WHEN PrevIsNationalityMatch = 1 THEN 'First Flat after same nationality owner'
                        WHEN NextIsNationalityMatch = 1 THEN 'First Flat before same nationality owner'
                        WHEN EmptyFloor = 1 THEN 'No Nationality Match, placed on empty floor'
                        WHEN EmptyFlatsEitherSide = 1 THEN 'Next flat with empty flats either side'
                        ELSE 'First Available Flat'
                    END
FROM    RankedFlats
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

**[Brazil Example - Floor 1, Flat 4](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e942/4)**

**[England Example - Floor 1, Flat 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e942/5)**

**[Spain Example - Floor 2, Flat 1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e942/6)**

**EDIT**

```
DECLARE @NewOwnerNationality VARCHAR(20) = 'BRAZIL';

WITH FlatOwnerNationality AS
(   SELECT  FlatMaster.Floor, 
            FlatMaster.FlatNo, 
            FlatMaster.IsOccupied,
            IsNationalityMatch = CASE WHEN OwnerMaster.OwnerNationality = @NewOwnerNationality THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM    FlatMaster
            LEFT JOIN OwnerMaster
                ON OwnerMaster.OwnerName = FlatMaster.OwnerName
), Flats AS
(   SELECT  FlatMaster.Floor,
            FlatMaster.FlatNo,
            FlatMaster.IsOccupied,
            EmptyFlatsEitherSide = CASE WHEN PrevFlat.IsOccupied = 'NO' AND NextFlat.IsOccupied  = 'NO' AND PrevFlat2.IsOccupied = 'NO' AND NextFlat2.IsOccupied  = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            EmptyFloor = CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN FlatMaster.IsOccupied = 'YES' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY FlatMaster.Floor) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            PrevIsNationalityMatch = ISNULL(PrevFlat.IsNationalityMatch, 0),
            NextIsNationalityMatch = ISNULL(NextFlat.IsNationalityMatch, 0)
    FROM    FlatMaster
            LEFT JOIN FlatOwnerNationality PrevFlat
                ON PrevFlat.Floor = FlatMaster.Floor
                AND PrevFlat.FlatNo = FlatMaster.FlatNo - 1
            LEFT JOIN FlatOwnerNationality NextFlat
                ON NextFlat.Floor = FlatMaster.Floor
                AND NextFlat.FlatNo = FlatMaster.FlatNo + 1
            LEFT JOIN FlatMaster PrevFlat2
                ON PrevFlat2.Floor = FlatMaster.Floor
                AND PrevFlat2.FlatNo = FlatMaster.FlatNo - 2
            LEFT JOIN FlatMaster NextFlat2
                ON NextFlat2.Floor = FlatMaster.Floor
                AND NextFlat2.FlatNo = FlatMaster.FlatNo + 2

), RankedFlats AS
(   SELECT  *,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PrevIsNationalityMatch DESC, 
                                                    NextIsNationalityMatch DESC, 
                                                    EmptyFloor DESC, 
                                                    EmptyFlatsEitherSide DESC,
                                                    Floor, 
                                                    FlatNo)
    FROM    Flats
    WHERE   IsOccupied = 'NO'
)
SELECT  Floor,
        FlatNo,
        MatchedOn = CASE WHEN PrevIsNationalityMatch = 1 THEN 'First Flat after same nationality owner'
                        WHEN NextIsNationalityMatch = 1 THEN 'First Flat before same nationality owner'
                        WHEN EmptyFloor = 1 THEN 'No Nationality Match, placed on empty floor'
                        WHEN EmptyFlatsEitherSide = 1 THEN 'Next flat with empty flats either side'
                        ELSE 'First Available Flat'
                    END
FROM    RankedFlats
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Its works like a charm.. But one change.. in requirement for 'Next flat with empty flats either side' i have mentioned two empty flst on either side. How to change with two empty flat?

Comment: I've added a new query that should work for 2 empty flats either side. It just does another 2 joins to the flat master table (on FlatNo + 2 and FlatNo - 2).